# Convert column to comma-separated string, maintaining scientific notation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have seen many people online ask about converting a column formatted list to a comma-separated list in the form of a string. I understand how to do that part, but I want the values I'm copying to the new string to maintain their scientific notation format.

```
A1 | 1.2E+00
A2 | 2.3E-03
A3 | 3.4E+04
```

I use the following to produce cells with the number and a following comma. Then those cells are transposed.

```
B1=A1&","
```

The problem is when B1 is defined, the values are reformatted to the "general" type. I want my transposed columns to look like this...

```
1.2E+00, | 2.3E-03 | 3.4E+04
```

But it's coming out like this instead

```
1.2, | 0.0023, | 34000,
```

Answer (score 2):

Scientific notation is just a format. Formats don't come across when a cell is referenced in a formula. Therefore, you need to explicitly format the number with scientific notation in the target formula.

Like this:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0.00E+00")&","&TEXT(A2,"0.00E+00")&","&TEXT(A3,"0.00E+00")
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.